# Python writing to file in python does not take place immediately (hangman game)

Tags: python, file-io

I just started writing a python code for a hangman game and I'm storing the words in a file. I also have given an option to add words based on users will.I have written the code for the same but for some reason the file is not updated until the program is relaunched.Please tell me where am i going wrong also I happen to have started programming on python after a long time so please keep in mind that it could be a mistake caused due to rustiness or memory faults.Here's my code(only regarding the file input output problem):

```
import os
def start():
    wordlist = open("wordlist_hangman",'a+')
    words= wordlist.read()
    choice=menu()
    if choice=='1':
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        game_start(wordlist,words)


    elif choice=='2':
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        add_word(wordlist)

    elif choice=='3':
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print words
        start()
    else:
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print('Invlaid input:must enter only 1,2 or 3 ')
        start()
def menu():
    print('Enter the number for the desired action.At any point in time use menu to go back to menu.')
    print('1.Start a new game.')
    print('2.Add words in dictionary.')
    print('3.See words present in dictionary')
    menu_choice=raw_input('>')
    return menu_choice
def add_word(wordlist):
    print("Enter the word you wish to add in ypur game")
    wordlist.write("\n"+raw_input('>'))
    start()
start()
```

Comment: you'd have to `wordlist.close()` to flush the file.

Comment: would closinbg and reopening the file do the job?

Comment: But it is better to use `with` instead. De-indenting flushes and closes the file

Comment: thanks that was helpful I certainly didn't know the use of with and the close was a memory refresher....i think you can mark it the thread as solved now

Comment: *You* mark the thread as closed by "accepting" the best, correct answer to your question. Do that by clicking the checkmark at the upper left of the answer. If a comment answered better, ask the commenter to put his content into a question and then accept it. Don't forget to upvote all helpful answers by clicking the up-arrow at the upper left of each question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python file object buffers the write operations until the buffer size is reached. In order to actually write the buffer to the file, call `flush()` if you want to continue writing or `close()` if you have finished:

```
wordlist.write("foo")
wordlist.flush()   # "foo" will be visible in file
wordlist.close()   # flushed, but no further writing possible
```

Alternatively, you can [open the file unbuffered](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open). That way, all writes will be committed immediately:

```
wordlist = open('file.txt', buffering=0)
```